# WordPress : How to make tablesort work with Genesis

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, tablesorter, genesis

I'm using WordPress and the Genesis framework and a child theme. I'm trying to use the jQuery plugin tablesorter to make a sortable table. I have a table created by PHP on a page template like so:
`<table id="propTable" class="tablesorter">`
In my `functions.php` file, I have this code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tablesort_script_add' );
function tablesort_script_add() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'jquery-tablesorter',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js',
    array('jquery')
  );
}
```

I've made sure that the directories are correct, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know if it is a problem with the tablesorter js file, or with the child theme/Genesis framework I'm using overriding or otherways interfering with the script.

It might also be a problem with me needing to write another script file to activate or implement the tablesorter for a specific table. If anyone could let me know which one of these I need to add or fix, and give me some pretty specific, beginner-level instructions on how to get there, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Are you including jQuery? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I included jQuery as a dependency for the tablesorter script above. And I'm now getting an error in the console that says `TypeError: $ is not a function`. My alert appears when I refresh the script, and I don't get a 404 when trying to load the script either, so I know it is at least loading right.

Comment: Include the [`debug` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#debug) and see what it says: `jQuery(function($) { $("#tablesorter").tablesorter( theme: 'blue', debug: true ); } );` - you might want to also load & include a theme.

Comment: Edit: I got it to work! Turns out that I had a loop when creating the table that assigned each row a <tbody> tag on default by accident, so that was causing only the first row to sort, which isn't very helpful haha.

Comment: LOL, please add that as an answer so that I can upvote it, and it may benefit others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my own problem!
So it seems that the loop I was using to go through posts and create my table was actually creating a new `<tbody>` tag for each row, so only the first row of the table was getting sorted.
 If anyone else is having the same problem with tablesorter, some other things I had to do were make sure I only loaded one jQuery (using it as a dependency is enough), and making sure that you pass the $ through as a parameter in your jquery.tablesorter, since wordpress automatically uses jquery's noconflict mode and the $ isn't valid as a global variable for jQuery.